# imagecreatefromstring() for a .bmp file

Tags: php, image-processing

What is the best way to use `imagecreatefromstring()` or an alternative method for `.bmp` file ?

This way:

```
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

for `.bmp` file I get :

```
imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format
```

But it works for `.png` and `.jpg` .

Comment: [Check this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromwbmp.php#86214) also note you need to have at least GD1.8

Answer (score 3):

For some strange reason, PHP doesn't have a built in `ImageCreateFromBMP()` function.

Fortunately, there is one here that you can drop into your code: http://php.net/imagecreate#53879